# BuildContext vs DisposableBuildContext in Flutter, what's the difference?

Tags: flutter

There is a [`DisposableBuildContext`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DisposableBuildContext-class.html) recently introduced in Flutter, I read the documentation of it, got the idea what it does, but couldn't find any use case or example where a regular `BuildContext` would fail and this work.

Can anyone shed some light on this by giving some example?

Comment: im not sure of it but some cases you need a disposed buildContext to render the next state so you better use disposableBuildContext

Comment: @KadriNadir Sorry, I couldn't relate anything to it. Would you mind providing any kinda code snippet?

Comment: maybe later on because i kinda have some work to do actually,and as i said i'm not sure of my answer. that's why i did post it as commentary .